# Is there an efficient way to stream Azure DevOps data to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-devops-analytics

I have recently been creating a POC using the new [DataDog/Azure DevOps Integration](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-azure-devops/).  The purpose of doing this is to aggregate all of my build/release logs, PR data, etc into DataDog to build insights, alerts, dashboards, etc.

The DataDog charts are very nice, but I would prefer to use Azure Log Analytics as this is where most of my company's log and metric data is aggregated already and the ability to correlate it would be helpful.  Note, I realize that Azure DevOps has Analytics charting and PowerBI integration, but I would like to use Log Analytics to store the metric and log data, if possible.

The Azure DevOps ServiceHooks do not have Azure Log Analytics as an option (see image below).  Maybe the trick is to push it to Azure Service Bus and then push it to Log Analytics?

I have looked at the [Azure DevOps Reporting documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/?view=azure-devops) and I didn't see anything obvious.

If anyone knows of any good blogs on pushing data from Azure DevOps to Log Analytics, I'd really appreciate it.  Unfortunately most of my searches come back with advice on how to use Azure DevOps to provision monitoring of external applications with App Insights and Log Analytic rather than the other way around.

I can imagine using a scheduled task calling the Azure DevOps API and pushing it into Log Analytics API, but that seems like the least elegant and most error prone solution.  Any thoughts on the best ways to monitor this data are appreciated.  Thanks!

[image: ServiceHooks picture]

Comment: This rahter won't answer you question, but are you aware of Audit log https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page ?

Comment: Thanks, I have been working on streaming the audit stream to Event Grid, it will be useful for SOC2 audits.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/auditing-streaming?view=azure-devops

Comment: @MichaelErpenbeck, if you find a solution, please post it as answer:).

Comment: @IvanYang, will do.